# How to set varchar default value

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create table where all varchar will have default value ''
It is big table so I do not want to use syntax like: a varchar(10) default ''
Is it possible to define it once for whole table?

Comment: Short answer: no. Default are defined on a column-by-column basis.

Comment: If you have knowledge of PHP you could write a script to do this for you.

Comment: You could also use copy & paste, or if you use vim, the "." key repeats the last edit.

Comment: If the table has so many identical columns that you don't want to type them all out you might need a better table design. You could ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

in Linux you can change the creates Tables with one line in **vi**

```
:1,$s/\cvarchar(\([0-9]*\))/VARCHAR(\1) DEFAULT ''/g
```

**Sample**

```
CREATE TABLE `elements1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Person1` varchar(8),
  `Person2` varchar(28) NOT NULL,
  `Person3` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `Person4` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Person5` varchar(28) NOT NULL,
  `Person6` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `tags` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

:1,$s/varchar(\([0-9]*\))/VARCHAR(\1) DEFAULT ''/g

CREATE TABLE `elements1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Person1` VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT '',
  `Person2` VARCHAR(28) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  `Person3` VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  `Person4` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  `Person5` VARCHAR(28) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  `Person6` VARCHAR(18) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  `tags` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```